# Python: Grid of 2D scatter plots (seaborn.PairGrid)

Tags: python

I have 7 features and I would like to plot all combinations of 2 features.  I would like to visualize this data as shown below. I can do it manually by adding sub plot after sub plot in matpltlib, but is there a function for this?  Does this type of plot have a special name?

Thank you

**Answer:**
seaborn.PairGrid
http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html

[image]

Comment: This is a specialized statistical plot usually refered to as a "pairplot".  Have a look at [`seaborn`'s `pairplot` function](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html).  Alternatively, it's actually not as complicated as you might think to do this with "bare" matplotlib -- it can be done in only a few lines.  Also, I'm fairly sure this is a duplicate question, but I can't find the duplicate at the moment...

Comment: Thank you.  I would love to know the duplicate name.  My problem was what vocabulary to google.

Comment: Might as well add the word pairplot in your title now so future readers can come stumble upon it. The function in Joe's comment seems to do what you want.

Comment: Well, I'm fairly sure I've seen this answered before, but I can't find it.  I've added an answer showing an example in both `seaborn` and "bare" `maplotlib`.  If someone comes across a good duplicate question, please feel free to mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is usually called a "pairplot".  A good option for specialty statistical plots such as this is `seaborn`, which is a wrapper around matplotlib focusing on statistical plotting.  As an example of using `seaborn.pairplot`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Generate Data.
nobs, nvars = 100, 5
data = np.random.random((nobs, nvars))
columns = ['Variable {}'.format(i) for i in range(1, nvars + 1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

# Make a pairplot using Seaborn
sns.pairplot(df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, you can also do this using "bare" matplotlib.  As a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate Data.
nobs, nvars = 100, 5
data = np.random.random((nobs, nvars))
columns = ['Variable {}'.format(i) for i in range(1, nvars + 1)]

# Make a pairplot:
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=nvars, nrows=nvars, sharex='col', sharey='row')
for (i, j), ax in np.ndenumerate(axes):
    if i == j:
        ax.annotate(columns[i], (0.5, 0.5), xycoords='axes fraction',
                    ha='center', va='center', size='large')
    else:
        ax.scatter(data[:,i], data[:,j], color='lightblue')
    ax.locator_params(nbins=6, prune='both')

plt.show()
```

[image]